# Use multiple \multicolumn commands in a LaTeX table to achieve column headers

Tags: tables, errors

I'm trying to code column headers in LaTeX so that each header spans two columns; however, the following code isn't working:

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Assets} \multicolumn{2}{c}{Liabilities and Equities} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(r){3-4}
Cash & \$13,152 & Short position (200 shares owed) & \$13,152 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

`Assets` should span the first two columns, and `Liabilities and Equities` should span the second pair. When I compile this, I get this error:

```
Misplaced \omit.
\multispan ->\omit 
                   \@multispan 
l.221 ...lticolumn{2}{c}{Liabilities and Equities}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you are doing this correct, but left out the column separator (`&`)on that line.

```
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
 \toprule
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{Assets} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Liabilities and Equities} \\
 \cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(r){3-4}
 Cash & \$13,152 & Short position (200 shares owed) & \$13,152 \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Gotta love those latex error descriptions!

Comment: LateX at 330 am... not a good combination. I just wasn't seeing it. Thank you *very* much.

Comment: I love using latex at 330 am in the morning.... ;-)

Comment: It appears I'm not the only one who uses LaTeX around 330am :|